# Access file upload data on ngform submit function in angular 5?

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular5, image-upload

I am having a ngform with file input along with other input fields.  Currently I am passing data to the component using ngmodel on submit.
But I don't know how to perform the file upload with ngmodel.In the backend I am using Laravel.

Currently I am able to get the file data in the component function **handleFileInput**.I want to pass this data along with other form input fields.How do I achieve that?

**Template code**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="file">Choose File</label>
<input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">                               
</div>
```

**Component code**

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
      this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    }
```

**onSubmit Method**

```
onSubmit() {
        this.loading = true;
        this._dataService.create(this.model, company_url).subscribe(data => {
            this.submitted = true;
            this.loading = false;
            this.companyForm.reset();
        },
            error => {
                this.loading = false; console.log(error);
                this.error_message = error;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you are doing with change detection is right.

Just you will have to create a formdata and submit that formdata with your post request.
You dont have to set the content type on your angular side, Angular does that job for you.

I am providing you my angular + node example hope this helps you.

I have used multer in my example to store the file.

Example

**Angular component**

```
// Create Variable for your file and formdata.
selectedFile: File = null;
fd = new FormData();

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

// Once the file change is detected append your file to your formdata and on submit post the request.
handleFileInput(event) {
      this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
      this.fd.append('file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    }

onSubmit() {
    this.http.post(url, this.fd)
    .subscribe((data)=>{console.log(data);});
}
```

**Node route file.**

```
var multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './upload')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});
var fs = require('fs');

router.post('/uploadprofile', auth, upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
   res.send('file uploaded');
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response.Currently I am passing data using ngmodel inside onSubmit and my content type is application/json.I have edited the question and added my onSubmit method.please check it.